# pip can't find distributions from within virtualenv

Tags: macos, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I set up a new virtualenv. From within it, pip cannot find any distributions. Outside of the env, it can. Here's the output:

```
(wagon-admin)[me@pjs-macbook-pro wagon-admin]$ pip install Django
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ when looking for download links for Django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for Django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ when looking for download links for Django
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django
No distributions at all found for Django
Storing complete log in /Users/me/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm on OSX, and created the virtual environment using `virtualenvwrapper`. `$ mkvirtualenv <env name>`

This happens for all packages, not just django.

Edit: Only similar thing I've found in my searching: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to python 2.7 and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but realized I hadn't activated my virtualenv. Once I activated it, the installation worked. Not sure why.

Looking at the command line you pasted, it looks like you activated your env, but just wanted to note this for others who happen to stumble across this.